# jQuery Accordion remove items inside

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, accordion

I am experiencing the following problem with JQUERY Accordion.

When I delete an item, the accordion loses its configuration as if the jquery accordion never be applied.

```
Example:
//INITIALIZE THE ACCORDION.
$("#divAccordion1").accordion();

//REMOVE DIV ITEM INSIDE ACCORDION PANEL 1.
$("#div1").children('div').eq(0).remove();
```

//AFTER REMOVE > Problem happens.

```
<div id="divAccordion1">
    <h3 style="padding: 10px;padding-left: 25px; ">ACCORDION 1</h3>
    <div id="div1" style="background-color: #EEEEEE;">
        <div style="width: 80px; height:  80px; display: inline-block; margin:10px;">
            <img src="" />
        </div>
        <div style="display: inline-block;  margin-top: 10px;">
            some data 1
        </div>
        <div style="display: inline-block;  margin-top: 10px; margin-left: 50px;">
            some data 2
        </div>
    </div>

    <h3 style="padding: 10px;padding-left: 25px; ">ACCORDION 2</h3>
        <div id="div2" style="background-color: #EEEEEE;">
            <div style="width: 80px; height:  80px; display: inline-block; margin:10px;">
                <img src="" />
            </div>
            <div style="display: inline-block;  margin-top: 10px;">
                some data 1
            </div>
            <div style="display: inline-block;  margin-top: 10px; margin-left: 50px;">
                some data 2
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You probably need to do an accordion [refresh()](http://api.jqueryui.com/accordion/#method-refresh) after you remove a div:

```
$("#divAccordion1").accordion('refresh');
```